# Incorrect UrlHelper in models in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urlhelper

I create Callback method at controller. I use Oauth authorization with social providers. When i create url for callback and send query for provider - provider are getting next url:

http:// 127.0.0.1 :8080/OAuth/CallBack

but this domain in this context - http://simple.com

How to use current context and this domain?
In debug mode project worked correctly, because project name matches with localy address.

```
var helper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
var actionCallback = helper.Action("CallBack", "OAuth", null, "http");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var actionCallback = url.Action("CallBack");
```

Comment: HttpContext cannot method "Current" into default controller if use.

Answer (score 0):

**I mean this. Thank you, I have already solved the problem.**

```
 public Uri GetUri(Controller.HttpContext.Request request){
    var request = Controller.HttpContext.Request;
    string uriStr = "";

    uriStr = String.Format("{0}", request.GetApplicationAbsoluteUrl);

    // bad variant! but is some fix-stub
    return new Uri(uriStr+"OAuth/Callback");
}

public static string GetApplicationAbsoluteUrl(this HttpRequestBase request) {
    string forwardedHost;
    string appPath = request.ApplicationPath ?? String.Empty;

    if (appPath.Length > 0 && appPath[appPath.Length - 1] != '/')
        appPath += '/';

    var authority = request.Url.Host == "127.0.0.1" && (forwardedHost = request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"]) != null
                  ? forwardedHost
                  : request.Url.Authority;

    return String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", request.Url.Scheme, authority, appPath);
}
```